# Uncaught ReferenceError: PhoneGap is not Defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am getting a strange issue regarding phonegap usage.  LogCat is spitting out an uncaught reference error regarding phonegap not being defined which is killing my application.  I am running cordova 2.2, and I am very new to phonegap.  Does anyone have any idea what might cause this?  The cordova file is being hotloaded into my application as a package, but even if I switch it and statically load it within the html I still get the error!  Please help!

```
    CordovaLog: Uncaught ReferenceError: PhoneGap is not Defined
```

This is mainly occuring when I use the SQLite Plugin by Brody, but it also happens with other phonegap functionality.  Also, if I add an event listener for device ready, it never fires! (I am guessing it already fired before the listener was added because it is nested pretty deep.)

Comment: you did the getting started android guide? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android

Comment: yes, I did.  If I hadn't, it wouldn't even deploy to the device...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using some out of date code the PhoneGap object is now "cordova". You should look for an updated version of that plugin.

Comment: No, it was deprecated out of the project in 2.0.0